# Struggling with snr rate

Tags: networking

I haven't had any problems with my internet connection...but i've been struggling for 3 months

My router shows very low upstream/downstream SNR

and this of course cause a huge lag/spikes and packet loss even when browsing or playing video games

this is my Line Status

Upstream max rate (kbit/s) 1082

Downstream max rate (kbit/s) 18960

Upstream line rate (kbit/s) 1018

Downstream line rate (kbit/s) 16382

Line standard ADSL2+

Channel type

Interleaved

Upstream SNR (dB) 8.6

Downstream SNR (dB) 6.8

Upstream line attenuation (dB) 9.5

Downstream line attenuation (dB) 16.1

Upstream output power (dBmV) 12

Downstream output power (dBmV) 18.7

Upstream CRC 0

Downstream CRC 10

Upstream FEC 0

Downstream FEC 6271

what should i do ?

Comment: You should speak to your ISP.

Comment: How far are yoy from the "other side" of the connection? There is probably not much you can do about it without your line provider/Telcio help, and even then maybe not. If you have any phones and filters on your line, try unplugging them all and see if it improves (then plug back and see if one should be changed).

Comment: If your problem is spikyness, ypu xan try getting a dd-wrt router and adding QoS to your connection to give your games better priority (assuming tje problem is bursts of other traffic)